# Rails 4 - Find position of a record inside table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say that I have a collection of `Emails`

```
-------------------------------------
| **recipient** | **Subject**        |
-------------------------------------
| john          | Hello              |
-------------------------------------
| john          | Hi                 |
-------------------------------------
| john          | Whats up?          |
-------------------------------------
| jane          | Hola               |
-------------------------------------
| jane          | Que tal?           |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to display all the emails, but explaining every email what position takes in the context of the recipient. Like this:

```
Mail #1 to: john
Subject: Hello

Mail #2 to: john
Subject: Hi

Mail #3 to: john
Subject: What's up?

Mail #1 to: jane
Subject: Hola

Mail #2 to: jane
Subject: Que tal?
```

This is my code so far:

```
Email.all.each do |email|
    <div>
        <div>Mail <%= ??? %> to: <%= email.recipient %></div>
        <div>Subject: <%= email.subject %></div>
    </div>
end
```

Comment: I have updated the question, in a simpler form, to see if I can make my point come across better

Comment: Note that you cannot assume an ordering of the records returned by the database unless you provide an explicit order-clause.

Comment: Well, since there is a `Email.first`, I was wondering if there was a `Email.index(email)`

Comment: Normally, every ActiveRecord record does indeed have an ID and these are normally in the order of the insertion of the records, but you should better order them explicitly by the creation date, which is also recorded by default in the field `created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each_with_index iterator:

```
Email.unread.each_with_index do |email, index|
    <div>
        <div>Mail <%= index+1 %> to: <%= email.recipient %></div>
        <div>Subject: <%= email.subject %></div>
    </div>
end
```

Comment: I have updated the question, because there is a case where that this solution doesn't work. Where there is more than one recipient

Comment: That's not the expected result. Dbuger wants to show the unread mails but number them relatively to all emails - from what I understand...

Comment: What I want to see is that ordinal (second, third, ...) of every email, from the point of view of the recipient

Comment: I have updated the question, to simplify the example. I hope it is clearer to understand that way

Comment: Group by only retrieves a single row from the db

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, are you looking for simple counter of the received messages for each recipient like this?

```
counter = {}
Email.all.each do |email|
  counter[email.recipient] ||= 0
    <div>
        <div>Mail <%= counter[email.recipient] += 1 %> to: <%= email.recipient %></div>
        <div>Subject: <%= email.subject %></div>
    </div>
end
```